# ImageMagick save image without noise around text

Tags: imagemagick

When I upload a flawless image with 100% quality to 9gag and download it, it looks like this (zoomed in):

[image]

it has 51kb

Now when I convert the 100% quality image with `ImageMagick` (`magick input.jpg -quality 76% result_imagemagick.jpg`) (the 76% quality to make it also 51kb like the one from 9gag) then it will look like this (zoomed in):

[image]

The one from 9gag has much less noise around letters!

How is 9gag doing this?

It's noticible that 9gag's image is slightly more blurry, but I take it over the noise any time.

I tried `-despeckle` but it only blurs the image and keeps the noise!

EDIT:

`magick identify -format "%Q"` shows that 9gag's image quality is 63(!!!!)%

How can there be only very few noise around the letters with that quality?

EDIT 2 to hopefully make it finally clear:

[image]

Comment: The issue is the JPG compression saves colors in 8x8 regions. So you are seeing variations due to the compression. If you remove the noise to fix it and save as JPG again, it will re-introduce the compression noise. Every read and write of JPG introduces more compression noise.

Comment: The original image doesn't have any noise and is 100 quality compression. Ok I make it more clear: I upload the flawless 100% quality jpeg to 9gag and the result is what you see in the first image. Then I convert the flawless 100% quality jpeg (so not the one I downloaded back from 9gag but the original) with 76% quality to match the size and the result is the second one. At the end both converted images have 51kb but the one that is converted by 9gag has much less noise and is slightly more blurry overall. I need to know how to do that

Comment: The original JPG probably has minimal noise visible since it is 100% compresses. But when you compress to 76%, you will see more noise (around dark regions with nearly constant white around them), since the compression is larger. This amplifies the 8x8 blockiness and it becomes more visible.

Comment: @fmw42 why does the 9gag conversion has less noise despite having the same size?

Comment: What is the sizes of your original 100% JPG and 76% JPG and why do you think the 100% one has more noise than the 65% compression one? Can you zip them and post to some free hosting site and put a link to them here? Do not upload without zipping.

Comment: ok check out the second edit, I hope this time it will be clear what the question and requirement is otherwise I don't know how else it can be explained @fmw42

Comment: The difference is likely the software used by the upload to read your JPG, then compress to 63%. When you use Imagemagick, then upload, Imagemagick reads and writes it compressed again so it adds some noise. Then you upload and that reads and writes with compression. So you have compressed twice, which will include more noise than compressing just once. It could also be in part the compression tables used by different JPG software. Some are more efficient than others

Comment: Wait you think that I convert the image with imagemagick before uploading it to 9gag? @fmw42

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood. I can only assume difference are in the quantization tables.

Comment: What are the chroma subsampling settings used by 9gag and by ImageMagick? (see `jpeg:sampling-factor` in `identify -verbose`). Large difference in file size from this.

Comment: it's for both 2x1,1x1,1x1 @xenoid